# aufs module not listed in lsmod

Tags: linux

I compiled my kernel(3.0.0+) from source with  aufs support and aufs is currently working on my server.

Why aufs module doesn't listed in lsmod? 
`lsmod | grep aufs` shows nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you compiled it builtin (i.e. not as a module) ?

if you have `CONFIG_AUFS_FS=m` in your kernel source `.config` file, then it is compiled as a module. (Alternatively, on a running kernel, the `.config` file used to compile the kernel is available gzipped in `/proc/config.gz` if enabled in ... your `.config`). If you have `CONFIG_AUFS_FS=y`, then it is NOT compiled as a module, but compiled builtin and, as such, is always available and always loaded, even if you don't need it. .

If you know you will always use it, it's fine to compile it builtin. Otherwise, on distribution kernels, you don't want to have all the drivers/fs/whatever loaded if you don't need them.